# Is Python's epsilon value correct?

Tags: python, numpy, numeric, numerical-methods

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Variant_definitions):

> Machine epsilon is defined as the smallest number that, when added to one, yields a result different from one

In Python, epsilon can be found using `sys.float_info.epsilon` and returns a value equivalent to 2^-52. However, I can add any number greater than 2^-53 to 1 and still get a result different to one.
But by the above definition of epsilon, adding any value less than epsilon to one should give one.
Does this mean that `sys.float_info.epsilon` is returning an incorrect value, or that Python is using some other definition of epsilon?

The following code illustrates this, with the floating point numbers printed out in hex format.

```
import sys
import numpy
print 'epsilon=%g' % sys.float_info.epsilon
# output: 2.22045e-16
epsilon = sys.float_info.epsilon
print 'epsilon(hex) = %s' % float.hex(epsilon)
# output:  0x1.0000000000000p-52

one = numpy.float64(1.0)

delta = float.fromhex('0x1.fffffffffffffp-53')
print 'delta = %s' % float.hex(delta)

print 'epsilon - delta = %s' % (float.hex(epsilon-delta))
#output: 0x1.0000000000000p-105

print '\n1.0 + epsilon = %s' % (float.hex(one+numpy.float64(epsilon)))
#output: 0x1.0000000000001p+0

print '\n1.0 + delta = %s' % (float.hex(one+numpy.float64(delta)))
#output: 0x1.0000000000001p+0
# since delta is smaller than epsilon, I expected 0x1.0000000000001p+0

delta1 = float.fromhex('0x1.0000000000001p-53')
print '\n1.0 + %s = %s' % (float.hex(delta1), float.hex(one+delta1))
#output: 0x1.0000000000001p+0
# since delta is smaller than epsilon, I expected 0x1.0000000000001p+0

delta2 = float.fromhex('0x1.0000000000000p-53')
# note: delta2 = epsilon / 2.0
print '\n1.0 + %s = %s' % (float.hex(delta2), float.hex(one+delta2))
# 0x1.0000000000000p+0
```

The resulting output is

```
epsilon=2.22045e-16
epsilon(hex) = 0x1.0000000000000p-52
delta = 0x1.fffffffffffffp-53
epsilon - delta = 0x1.0000000000000p-105

1.0 + epsilon = 0x1.0000000000001p+0

1.0 + delta = 0x1.0000000000001p+0

1.0 + 0x1.0000000000001p-53 = 0x1.0000000000001p+0

1.0 + 0x1.0000000000000p-53 = 0x1.0000000000000p+0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that what you you are seeing is how Python's `float` type handles rounding when it runs out of precision. The Wikipedia text you quoted describing `epsilon` appears to leave this part out.

In your example, `1 + delta` gets rounded up to `1 + epsilon`. Even though a `float` can specify the differences between `delta` and `epsilon`, it cannot represent the difference between `1 + delta` and `1 + epsilon`. As you have noticed (with your `delta2` test), the largest number that gets rounded down to `1` rather than up to `1 + epsilon` appears to be `1 + epsilon/2`.

So, a correct definition of what `epsilon` means in Python might be:

`epsilon` is the smallest positive floating point number such that `(1 + epsilon) - 1` equals `epsilon`.

Comment: I don't think it's Python's rules, it's IEEE's. I like your conclusion, except that zero meets the requirement too. Perhaps if you restated it to be "the smallest *nonzero* floating point ..."

Comment: Good point about zero. In fact, probably `-2/epsilon` (`-2**53`) would count too (while being much "smaller" in the "closer to negative infinity" sense), so I've adjusted my definition to specify a positive number.

Answer (score 4):

That definition is wrong: **machine epsilon** is the number eps such that 1+eps is the next number after 1.  Thus with standard rounding, u = eps/2 is the smallest number that when added to 1 gives a value greater than 1.  This quantity u is often called the **unit roundoff** or **machine unit**.
(For IEEE64, eps=2^(-52), u = 2^(-53).)

By the way, for most practical purposes, the unit roundoff u is more useful than eps: for example, u is the maximum relative error when a value is rounded to a normalized machine number.

Reference: Higham, *Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms*, pages 37, 38.